# Bind jar:test-jar to package phase

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-jar-plugin

I have a pom snippet containing the following:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.jason.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>resources/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-test-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When i run "mvn package", the plugin does not execute and my test jar does not get created. When i run "mvn jar:test-jar" my jar gets created. Does anyone know why that might be?

Thank you kindly,
Jason

Comment: Is this plugin configuration in the `<plugins>` section of the `<project>`? Or is it in the `<plugins>` section of the `<pluginManagement>` section?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose. it is in the <plugins> section of the project

Comment: Add `<id>TheNexId</id>` in the `<execution>` area...

Comment: @khmarbaise. Thanks for the suggestion khmarbaise. I updated the pom snippet but still no joy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misplaced the `<executions>` block: it should be outside of the `<configuration>` one.
As you wrote it, it means that you pass a structure of parameters named "executions" to the configuration of the maven jar plugin, which is simply ignored.

Here's the correct configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                ... your configuration data ...
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-test-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note that specifying the "package" phase for your execution isn't necessary, since the maven jar plugin is attached by default to this phase.